# Shingle filter factory startOffset must be non-negative, and endOffset must be >= startOffset

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I am using lucene version 4.4 with these analyzers:

```
worddelimeter, patternFilter, synonyms, lowercase,
stopwords, kStemFilter, shingle, trimfilter.
```

Analyzers are listed in the order in which I use them. When I try to add the documents I get the following exception:

```
startOffset must be non-negative, and endOffset must be >= startOffset,
            startOffset=37571,endOffset=37569
```

This exception occurs only for a specific file. However when I change the order and place `stopwords` filter before `worddelimeter` it works fine. But that's not the right way to do it!

Why does that happen? Under what circumstances could one filter alter the data in a way to cause that Exception?

Comment: Could you add Details (like the file where that happens?)

Comment: Also please add the whole stack trace of the exception. As it stands now the question is hard to solve.

Answer (score 0):

It's not you, it's a known limitation/bug in WordDelimiterFilter.  See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-5111   Rob Muir added a patch today so it appears you may be in luck for Lucene 4.8.